# How to open the default email app in iOS without using a mailto link?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I'm using passwordless sign up and need to have a "Open Email App" at the end of the sign up flow.

All the instructions I find are for opening the default mail app using a `mailto` link which will open a message compose view.

I just need to open the default email app so the user can open the message I just sent them.

Comment: Is this really necessary, I don’t think I have ever seen an app do this? The normal thing is to just inform the user that you have sent an email. What if the mail service is slow for instance, it would be a bad user experience to be sent to the email app if there is no mail to read.

Comment: You can use `UIApplocation.shared.open(URL(string: "message://"))` for that, but yeah, as it is mentioned above, it is better just to inform a user about the delivery channel of this link, and let them check it manually